# Targetting Iframe with Form causes new window to open

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I am working in chrome v. 12.

I have a jquery call which creates an iframe

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('<iframe />').appendTo('body').attr({'id': 'iframeUploader', 'name':'iframeUploader'}).hide();
});
```

when I use a form to upload, chrome opens a new window instead of targetting the iframe

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php?productID=1074" target="iframeUploader">
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? I'm pulling my hair out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read here: http://terminalapp.net/submitting-a-form-with-target-set-to-a-script-generated-iframe-on-ie/
Indeed, after I switched to this:

```
 $('<iframe name="iframeUploader"/>').appendTo('body').attr({'id': 'iframeUploader'});
```

it worked. Tried it in IE8 and FF3.6

Answer (score 2):

If you are setting the `target` attribute of form statically (i.e. while creating form itself and) and setting it to an `iframe`, then the response is opened in a new tab/window.

While if you set the `target` attribute dynamically just before submitting the form using javascript/jQuery, the response is received within the same window into targeted `iframe`.

Answer (score -1):

The `form target` attribute allows the developer to target the form to a named window or frame - I don't think you can target an iframe in this way - and is deprecated.

Comment: This is not true.  You can target an `iframe` using its `name` attribute.