# Chrome ignores target attribute inside Angular2 app

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, angular

I want to open a link in an iframe like it is described in W3Schools:

```
<iframe height="300px" width="100%" src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"> </iframe>

<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>
```

When I put it inside an Angular2 app like:

```
<my-app>  
  <iframe height="300px" width="100%" src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
  <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>    
</my-app>
```

then it works in IE 11 fine, but in Chrome the link is opening in a new tab.

It works fine in Chrome, if it is outside of Angular2 app.

See example in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TNfGuCFZ3cl5IwFHUhIw?p=preview

Any experience on that issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the iframe dynamically with javascript Chrome will honor the target.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309782/targetting-iframe-with-form-causes-new-window-to-open).